# How to display the content of a variable in plain text in Twig?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

How to filter the content of a variable in Twig so that it displays plain text ? Currently the content is rendered with HTML tags and I want to render only the text for the following codes :

```
{{ store_entity.name.value }}
{{ store.address }}
{{ store.field_professionnel_id_ets }}
{{ store.mail }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`striptags` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html) :

> The striptags filter strips SGML/XML tags and replace adjacent whitespace by one space:

For example :

```
{{ store.mail|render|striptags }}
```

*(`render` is usually automatic/implicit in twig so we don't need to call it most of the time, here we make it explicit because we need to render HTML before `striptags` comes into play).*